# How to make user input relate to a variable?

Tags: java, variables, input, user-input

I don't know how to phrase this question precisely, but this is what I want to achieve
(I am implementing the Towers of Hanoi illustration using stacks:

This is inside the `main()` function:

```
System.out.println("Type the source pole number and the destination pole number");
int a = reader.nextInt();
int b = reader.nextInt();
boolean move = moveDics(a, b);
```

These are the stacks which represent the 3 poles:

```
    Stack<Integer> pole1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> pole2 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> pole3 = new Stack<Integer>();
```

I want to change the stacks based on the user input, and to do so I need to related to the variables pole1, pole2, pole3 (to preform any action, like `pole1.pop()`).

And this is my question: how can I user the user input - an integer - to relate to the poles, other than multiple if() statements or a switch case statement? Something like `pole + "x".pop()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Good solution**

Don't make many variables like that.

You can put them all in an array :

```
Stack[] poles = new Stack[3];
for (int i=0; i<poles.length; i++) poles[i] = new Stack<Integer>();
```

Then you can access your poles using `poles[yourInteger]`.

A variant (based on Jeffrey's comment) :

```
List<Stack<Integer>> poles = new ArrayList<Stack<Integer>>();
for (int i=0; i<poles.size(); i++) poles[i] = new Stack<Integer>();
```

Then you can access your poles using `poles.get(yourInteger)`.

Note that as soon as you start to do more complex things on those poles, you'd have to consider embedding them in a class. I personally try to avoid collections of collections or arrays of collections as they tend to be confusing.

**Not very good solution**

You may use a switch :

```
public Stack<Integer> getPole(int i) {
    switch(myInteger) {
    case 1:
        return pole1;
    case 2:
        return pole2;
    case 3:
        return pole3
    }
    return null;
}
```

use it with

```
Stack<Integer> pole = getPole(yourInteger);
```

**Crazy solution**

You may, if you want, access your variables by name using reflexion.

To do this, you first fetch the Field instances of your class :

```
Field stackField = MyClass.class.getField("pole"+myInteger);
```

Then you have to get the methods of this field's value, and call them. This will be slow, many LOC and many try/catch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I should have figured out it's much easier to implement it using stacks array. Is there a way to achieve what I was trying to do, anyway?

Comment: @dystroy You can't make generic arrays. Try a `List<Stack<Integer>>`.

Comment: @amiregelz Yes, it would be easy to do what you want with your diverse variables, using reflection, and maybe I'll add the code to do it to my answer, but really, **don't!**.

Comment: @amiregelz I added other solutions but only the first one would be used by a sane and experienced java coder.

Comment: @amiregelz List is an interface, you must use a concrete implementation like this : `List<Stack<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Stack<Integer>>();`

Comment: @dystroy It seems a little bit confusing (like you said previously, collection of a collection), so I think I'll make it an Int stack instead of a generic one, and make an array of stacks like you suggested.

Comment: Good. Glad to have been helpful :)

Comment: @Jeffrey thanks : I hadn't realized at first that I had defined a generic array. I fixed the code.

Comment: I know you wrote "Crazy Solution". But I just want to point out that please developers for everything you love don't use reflection in such cases, it's the worst nightmare of your fellow "maintenance" developer.